# Compiling header files in ubuntu. What do I type in terminal?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, terminal

I'm pretty sure this is a simple question but I've searched online for about half an hour.

I have 3 files:

02_01.c

```
#include <stdio.h>          // Notice the library included in the header of this file
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "myLibrary.h"      // Notice that myLibrary.h uses different include syntax

#define MAX_LENGTH 21.8
#define WORK_WEEK  5

int main(void) {
    function1();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

myLibrary.c

```
void function1(void){
    puts("It works :)");
}

void function2(void){
    //This function does nothing as well
}
```

myLibrary.h

```
#ifndef MYLIBRARY_H_
#define MYLIBRARY_H_

void function1(void);
void function2(void);

#endif /* MYLIBRARY_H_ */
```

First, I navigate to my working directory.
Normally in a file with no local headers I would type:

```
gcc -o 02_01 02_01.c
./02_01
```

and it would work.

I've tried a variety of things like:

gcc -o 02_01 02_01.c myLibrary.c

which gives me an error "implicit declaration of function 'puts'

gcc -o myLibrary myLibrary.c which also gives the same error.

What should I be typing in the terminal in ubuntu?

So I'm assuming that the puts() function in myLibrary.c is not connected to 02_01.c which is where I include stdio.h.

Comment: you have to include the header where the function is used, not in another .c file. gcc cannot make the link between both files. what is your question? you don't want to change the contents of the files?

Comment: The code in `myLibrary.c` uses standard I/O functions, that are declared in `<stdioh.>`. So perhaps you should include that header file in `myLibrary.c`? Header files are only part of the current [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) being compiled, they don't spill over to other independent translation units. (A translation unit is basically a single source file and all its included header files, and as such is an independent unit.)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you. That's what I do in C++. I'm actually following a video lesson from Lynda and these were the files provided as an example. They used Eclipse in Windows so maybe that's why it worked for them and not for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you, I did just that and it works perfectly.

Comment: You learn about [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), you write a good `Makefile`, then you just type `make`

Answer (score 1):

You must include required headers in every file, where you using included functions. In your case, you must include `#include <stdio.h>` in beginning of your `myLibrary.c` file.

Also, you probably want to build `.a` library and link with it later.

So, finally:

1. Compile lib:

   ```
        gcc -c -o mylib myLibrary.c
   ```
2. Make static lib:

   ```
        ar rcs libMyLib.a mylib
   ```
3. Compile app and link together:

   ```
        gcc -o 02_01 02_01.c -L. -lMyLib
   ```